# MongoDB: Spring Aggregation operation throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing a simple Aggregation operation. Following is my code:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("publisherId").is(Integer.parseInt(publisherId)))
       , group("publisherId").count().as("total").sum("name").as("name").sum("zip").as("zip")
);

AggregationResults<DataContentResult> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation , DataContent.class, DataContentResult.class);
List<DataContentResult> theResult = result.getMappedResults();
```

Here is the class that maps the MongoDB Collection:

```
@Document(collection = "DataContent")
public class DataContent{

@Id
private String _id;

private Integer publisherId;

private Integer name;
private Integer zip;

public String get_id() {
        return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
}

public Integer getPublisherId() {
        return publisherId;
}

public void setPublisherId(Integer publisherId) {
        this.publisherId = publisherId;
}

public Integer getName() {
        return name;
    }

public void setName(Integer name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getZip() {
    return zip;
}

public void setZip(Integer zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}

}
```

And I have the class which I want to return my result as:

```
@Entity
public class DataContentResult implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6215495047789780758L;

String publisherId;
long total;
private Integer name;
private Integer zip;

public String getPublisherId() {
    return publisherId;
}

public void setPublisherId(String publisherId) {
    this.publisherId = publisherId;
}

public long getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(long total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public Integer getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(Integer name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getZip() {
    return zip;
}

public void setZip(Integer zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(Lorg/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationResults;
[INFO]  at de.it2media.dps.statistics.server.dao.impl.MainMongoDAOImpl.getDataContentFilterStatisticData(MainMongoDAOImpl.java:124) ~[classes/:na]
[INFO]  at de.it2media.dps.statistics.server.service.impl.MainServiceMongoImpl.getDataContentFilterStatisticData(MainServiceMongoImpl.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
[INFO]  at de.it2media.dps.statistics.server.controller.HomeController.getDataContentFilterStatisticData(HomeController.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587) ~[gwt-servlet-2.7.0.jar:na]
[INFO]  ... 47 common frames omitted
```

As you can see, my code is pretty basic. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Note that I have tried running `DataContentResult` class both with and without `@Entity` and `implements Serializable` and there is no effect. So how come I get `NoSuchMethodError`? And what does that error mean anyway?

**EDIT:** Following are the dependencies in my pom.xml. I'm not sure if library versions have anything to do with this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: normally NoSuchMethodError tell the user that the method that he is trying to invoke a method that does not exist, are sure that you are using the same libraries to run and compile your project, same versions ?

Comment: @Koitoer I have edited my answer and specified the dependency versions I'm using. I'm not sure what sort of conflict can library versions cause in my case.

Comment: I dont think you need to have mongodb-driver and mongo-java-driver as in maven repository said : mongo-java-driver  "The MongoDB Java Driver uber-artifact, containing mongodb-driver, mongodb-driver-core, and bson " I think mongo-java-driver will be enough, but that is not causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use you code lines and I am able to get

```
10:49:39.342 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - Executing aggregation: { "aggregate" : "DataContent" , 
"pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "publisherId" : 10}} , 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$publisherId" , "total" : { "$sum" : 1} , "name" : { "$sum" : "$name"} , "zip" : { "$sum" : "$zip"}}}]}
```

My pom.xml is at follows.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mongodb.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mongodb.driver}</version>
    </dependency>

<org.mongodb.version>1.5.5.RELEASE</org.mongodb.version>
<org.mongodb.driver>3.0.0-beta3</org.mongodb.driver>
```

Also tried with  `<org.mongodb.driver>3.2.1</org.mongodb.driver>` and it works, what make me think that one of your imports is not correct.

check this [github](https://github.com/koitoer/mongo-db-support/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/koitoer/spring/mongodb/Launcher.java) with the correct imports.

Comment: My imports are the same as yours. But I changed the version of ´org.springframework.data´ from 1.5.2 to 1.5.5 and it magically started working. So I guess it was a version problem. Still not sure what exactly happened and why 1.5.2 works for you and not me. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Yes very weird, I see the API in the same format in both versions, but who knows. xD